# Debugging with pycharm and python

Tags: pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc6ua.png)I am trying to debug the following code:

```
import gdal

def create(folder):
    src_ds=gdal.Open(folder)

    subdataset = 'HDF5:"' +'E:\Ioannis_MarineEO_Task1\SST\VIRS\V2019156000000.L2_SNPP_SST.nc' + '":' + '//geophysical_data/sst'
    src_ds_sd = gdal.Open (subdataset)

    #
    options=gdal.WarpOptions(tps=True,dstSRS='EPSG:4326')
    temp=gdal.Warp('E:/Ioannis_MarineEO_Task1/sst1.tif',src_ds_sd,options=options)

    src_ds = gdal.Open(temp)
    temp = None
    upx, xres, xskew, upy, yskew, yres = src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    print(upx, xres, xskew, upy, yskew, yresv)
    return

create('E:\Ioannis_MarineEO_Task1\SST\VIRS\V2019156000000.L2_SNPP_SST.nc')
```

To do that i am using pycharm. However when i run it the variables section is disconnected. Any ideas?

I have attached an image.

Comment: It would be helpful not to roll back approved edits of your question that clearly improve readability.

Comment: I wanted to approve them however i didn t know how

Comment: Is this the only project that pycharm has problems with for you?

Comment: Yeap............